# RHEL 7 moving files from 1 VM to 10 at one time

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, rhel-7

I have 11 VM’s on RHEL 7. I only have access to the files on 1 VM and have to SCP them over to the other 10. Is there an easier was to do it then hitting the up arrow every time and changing it to the next number of that VM? Thanks In advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is their an easier way, absolutely, but that would require changing the configuration of the VMs